# Exception in MediaPlayer.setDataSource() method

Tags: android, exception

In the class I have this field:

```
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

And every time some sound needs to be played, the following method is being called:

```
private synchronized void playSound(int sound) {
      try {
                mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + sound));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        while (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            // waiting while it is already playing
                        }
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                    }
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

The problem is this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.app, PID: 28893
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1128)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1012)
                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:968)
                      at com.speechsynthesizer.TextProcessor.playSound(TextProcessor.java:92)
```

**URI source is OK**, I have checked it.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadocs say:

> IllegalStateException - if it is called in an invalid state

Looking at the [valid/invalid states table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States) any state besides `IDLE` would cause this exception. My guess is that `playSound` is being called twice, and because it is already preparing/playing during the second time the state is invalid.